# Checking External Disk Health

Tags: disk

I have have a 2TB external luks encrypted hard disk.  I want to check the disk's health, however the gnome-disks utility does not give the option to "repair" or "check" the file system and smarttools says that the disk is not compatible, so my question is:   How do I check the disk health of my external drive?

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.84 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Disk model: Elements 25A2   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FE88818A-C2BA-46B2-A911-A9FFC364F413
```

and

```
Disk /dev/mapper/luks-8b6272af-069d-4f00-9a33-57472f0aed47: 1.84 TiB, 2000361095168 bytes, 3906955264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: What is the filesystem in that disk? (and use a tool compatible with that filesystem)

Comment: @Rinzwind  should be linux ext4 and I have added output of fdisks to my post.